# python selenium execute script confirmation box, getting results back

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, confirm, execute-script

When running a scraping tool I am in the process of writing I need to interact with the user but prefer not via the console as that means switching between the console and the browser.

Problem is I can't figure out how to get the results, for example:

```py
r = self.driver.execute_script('return confirm("test press ok or cancel");')
```

results in none, either when I press ok or cancel. I've first had to wait until the alert pops up then wait again until I get
`NoAlertPresentException` using the usal try/except with

```py
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
```

and carrying on until I hit the `NoAlertPresentException`. Now the question is does doing `alert = ....` nuke the

```py
r = self.driver.execute_script
```

by any chance if thats the case how do I get the value of a python selenium script created alert and is it even possible ?